# ls permission denied even with execute permissions

Tags: permissions, chmod, chown

I chowned recusively `/srv/site` to `www-data:www-data` and chmodded it recursively with `ug+rwx`. I then added myself to group `www-data`.

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G www-data cyrus
$ sudo chgrp -R www-data /srv/site
$ sudo chmod -R ug+rwX /srv/site
```

However, why do I still get permission denied?

```
$ ls /srv/site
ls: cannot open directory /srv/site: Permission denied

$ cd /srv; ls -la   
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root     4096 Aug 13 02:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root     root     4096 Aug 11 21:20 ..
drwxrwx--x 10 www-data www-data 4096 Aug 13 02:42 site
```

Comment: type `id` as your user.  what groups are you in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you logged in again.  Group membership is not normally reset once a user has logged in.

Comment: Run the `id` or `groups` commands to see your current groups. You will probably find that your group list has not been updated. It doesn't take effect on existing processes/sessions/etc.

Comment: Yes, when I ran `groups`, `www-data` was not there. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out you have to re-login to refresh a group vector.

To not loose the context of your work (eg. other opened terminals), you might consider

```
user$ su - user
```

or

```
user$ newgrp www-data
```

then from there on you can spawn new programs with complete group vector.

In case of `newgrp`, what you are ending up is your primary group to be `www-data` (in this case), which is significant eg. when creating new files.

In case of `su`, I wonder how to achieve the same effect with `sudo` (`sudo -iu user` doesn't refresh the group vector).